# Get tommorrow day of the week with date("l") PHP

Tags: php, date

Let's assume I get the day of the week with this

```
$monday = date("l");
```

which works but now, I would like to get the next two days like

```
$date = ("Y-m-d");
$tuesday = date('l', strtotime('+1 day',$dateaa));
$wednesday = date('l', strtotime('+3 day',$dateaa));
```

but I get the `Monday Monday` when I echo `$tuesday` and `$wednesday`

Comment: You haven't put in your code how you get `$dateaa`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure?

```
$dateaa = strtotime('last sunday');
echo $wednesday = date('l', strtotime('+3 day', $dateaa)); // wednesday

$dateaa = strtotime('last monday');
echo $thursday = date('l', strtotime('+3 day', $dateaa)); // thursday
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$days = array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
$today = date('w');
$nextTwoDay = $today + 2;
if ($nextTwoDay > 6) $nextTwoDay = $nextTwoDay - 6;
echo $days[$nextTwoDay];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Piotr Grudniewski